# C# Spam in output, how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to make program in c# that will found value and show it in text box, but it's not a problem... When I tried to show this value, program spam in 1 text box, so it's impossible to read something.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string input = client.DownloadString("example.com");
            textBox2.AppendText(input);
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^<b>](.*)[^</b>]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match match;
            for (match = regex.Match(input); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
            {
                foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("Value {0}", group));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1 Text box should show only the value
2 Text box show html code from page

Comment: Your regular expression is matching an awful lot more than you meant it to. `[^...]` defines a negative character class.

Comment: is `textBox1` an actual Control or is it an html element?

Comment: I think your regular expression isn't doing what you want. Are you trying to find something like `<b>This is bold text</b>`, and then show just the text between `<b>` and `</b>`?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ryDLo Here is my program visualisation

Comment: @JimMischel that can be my problem i will check it

Comment: Yep i found secound value that start with <b>

Comment: Thank you Jim, u found my problem. I should correct regex pattern

Comment: @MKKL Parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea, you'd better try some HTML parser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: I recommend to use HtmlAgilityPack for HTML parsing - https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Please do not use regex to parse HTML. You will awaken [the great devourer of worlds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSQuery to parse your HTML:

https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

```
CQ dom = "<div>Hello world! <b>I am feeling bold!</b> What about <b>you?</b></div>";

string bold = dom["b"].First().InnerText;
```

You can select elements like JQuery